# How can I set id using Html.EditorFor with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to set a field id as follows:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Order, new { id = string.Format("Order_{0}", Model.Row) })
```

but this results in the following and it seems my id is not being set:

```
<input type="text" value="334" name="item.Order" id="item_Order" class="text-box single-line">
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong. I checked the allowable formats for EditorFor and looked on google for examples but I could not see anything that matched what I need.

Comment: Add '@' before 'id' like '@id='

Comment: id is NOT a keyword in C# so no need to use the @, this is only needed with keywords like @class

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should change to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Order, new { id = string.Format("Order_{0}", Model.Row) })
```

The second parameter of `@Html.EditorFor` is for view data, not for html attributes

Comment: Thanks. This worked great. Now I am wondering what the difference is between Html.EditorFor and Html.TextBoxFor. Is the difference that EditorFor uses the templates?

Comment: Yes, EditorFor is for custom type/template.

Comment: But what about the original question? What if you want/need to use EditorFor - How then to set the id?

Comment: JonK, see Svetoslav Petrov's answer lower down. I think that should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 24):

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Order, null, string.Format("Order_{0}", Model.Row))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it answer the question actually asked, rather than changing it.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is pretty old, but all I needed to do was the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.EndDate, 
                new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = @endID } })
```

You can give it whatever classes or id that you want/need. I have this earlier in my page as well to create a different ID for each item:

```
string endID = "end-" + @item.ID;
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 5):

have you tried creating an editor template for your `x.Order`?

have this on your editor template:

```
<input type="text" id="@ViewData["id"]">
```

and use this on your view page:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Order, new { id = string.Format("Order_{0}", Model.Row) })
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can override the ID attribute when using the strongly typed helpers. But you can use the other non-model type:

```
@Html.Editor(string.Format("Order_{0}", Model.Row), Model.Order)
```

This will use the first parameter as the ID and the second as the default value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use EditorFor, you can do this:

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Order, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "YOUR_ID_HERE"})`

For the above example it would be: 
 
`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Order, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = $"Order_{0}" } })`

Svetlosav's answer *looks* good but it will mess up your data binding. If you use that answer, check to see if your model is populating as expected and not with a default value (null, false, 0, etc..).