# How can i set the html id attribute in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to configure datepicker in my MVC 5 form. I have included all the reference libraries like Jquery, datepicker etc.

Following is the line from MVC razor view, which is created by Visual Studio in a result for MVC 5 scaffolding.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.News_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
```

any help in this regard

Answer (score 5):

Just add the id property to the html-attributes. That will override the default id generated by the editorfor-helper-methode.

Look at this post:
[How can I set id using Html.EditorFor with MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189006/how-can-i-set-id-using-html-editorfor-with-mvc3)

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.News_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "my_custom_id" }})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this solution with MVC5 .net 4.5.1. I was trying to set manually the form Id because I was going to have several forms in the same page and I needed to control then separatelly with JS  :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Products", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divEmp"+Model.Id }, htmlAttributes : new { id = "form_" + Model.Id } ))
{

}
```

Enfasis in last parameter: `htmlAttributes : new { id = "form_" + Model.Id }`

It is the same with `@Html.BeginForm()` and other helpers.

The `htmlAttributes:` part is not really necessary.